# Mongodb get information to make some stats

Tags: mongodb

I need to get information from my MongoDB database, but I cant realize the request with my actual skill...

Can you help me making it ?

I have to get :
- the sum of an object attribute {isDone : true}
- filter by two dates 
- group by the month concerned

Thanks for advance

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are asking. I already provided a date range like you mentioned. And the command you provided has a grammar mistake. field comes first, not the value.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/).

```
db.coll_name.aggregate([
    {$match: {date_field: {$gt: new Date("...")}, date_field: {$lt: new Date("...")}}, // date range
    {$project: {isDone: "$isDone", year: {$year: "$year"}, month: {$month: "$month"}}}, // extract year/month and isDone
    {$group: {_id: {year: "$year", month: "$month"}, count: {$sum: 1}}
]);
```